# What type of statistics test would I run for 2 different treatments assessed using 5 measurements at 4 different time points?

Tags: statistics

I have a study in which there are 2 groups: control vs drug. All individuals were assessed at 4 different developmental time points and I ran 5 tests at each time point. My goal is to see how the drug impacted their overall performance throughout development (i.e. how the drug affects development). I can't seem to figure out which type of test this would be. I believe it would be a repeated measures style of ANOVA, but I can't determine what it would be specifically. If anyone could give their input, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are the 5 tests 1 test + 4 re-tests (the same experiment repeated 5 times), or are they 5 different tests as part of some test battery? What time points are they? Developmentally, so e.g. kids at different ages? What kind of outcome measure do you have? Qualitative or quantitative? Is it a Likert scale or continuous? As of now this question can't be answered efficiently

Comment: Also, would this question be a better fit for CrossValidated?  I am not sure how it is strictly a psych.SE question.